# Combining gridExtra and Facet_wrap/Facet_grid for a grid of double-charts

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I have two metrics I need to plot on two differents line charts (very different scale).

Using `gridExtra`, I am able to put one on top of the other:

```
chart.top = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Days, y=Estimated.revenue)) + geom_line()
chart.bottom = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Days, y=Units.sold)) + geom_line()
chart = grid.arrange(chart.top,chart.bottom, heights = c(1/2, 1/2))
```

Now I would like to create a grid of these double-charts with `facet_wrap` / `facet_grid`, splitting my data with an additional dimension (here *Brands*). Is it possible? Something like below does not work:

```
chart = grid.arrange(chart.top,chart.bottom, heights = c(1/2, 1/2)) + facet_wrap(~ Brands, ncol=3)
```

And if I do something like below, I end up with one grid per chart types rather than one grid of double-charts:

```
chart.top = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Days, y=Estimated.revenue)) + geom_line()
    + facet_wrap(~ Brands, ncol=3)
chart.bottom = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Days, y=Units.sold)) + geom_line()
    + facet_wrap(~ Brands, ncol=3)
chart = grid.arrange(chart.top,chart.bottom, heights = c(1/2, 1/2))
```

**EDIT:**

**Sample data (dput(df)):**

```
structure(list(Days = structure(c(16685, 16685, 16686, 16686, 
16687, 16687), class = "Date"), Brand = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Brand 2", "Brand 3"), class = "factor"), 
    Units.sold = c(145, 106, 1, 2, 2, 51), Estimated.revenue = c(0.073330174, 
    0.211338814, 0.000496881, 0.006588271, 0.001008714, 0.047465918
    )), .Names = c("Days", "Brand", "Units.sold", "Estimated.revenue"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Sample Code:**

```
df = read.csv(file="rules_data2.csv", header=TRUE)
df$Estimated.revenue = as.numeric(gsub(",","", df$Estimated.revenue))
df$Units.sold = as.numeric(gsub(",","", df$Units.sold))
df$Days = as.Date(df$Days,"%m/%d/%Y")

#Option 1 - Work for one brand, showing 2 charts on top of each other
df1 = subset(df, Brand == "Brand 2")
chart.top = ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=Days, y=Units.sold)) +
  geom_line(size=1)
chart.bottom = ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=Days, y=Estimated.revenue)) +
  geom_line(size=1)
chart = grid.arrange(chart.top,chart.bottom, heights = c(1/2, 1/2))
```

**Option 1 Output**
[image: Option 1 Output]

```
#Option 2 - Show charts for my 2 brands but group them by metrics shown rather than Brand
chart.top = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Days, y=Units.sold)) +
  geom_line(size=1) + facet_wrap(~ Brand, ncol=1)
chart.bottom = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Days, y=Estimated.revenue)) +
  geom_line(size=1) + facet_wrap(~ Brand, ncol=1)
chart = grid.arrange(chart.top,chart.bottom, heights = c(1/2, 1/2))
```

**Option 2 Output**
[image: Option 2 Output]

Comment: could you `dput(df)` to make it reproducible?

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to look at this. I have added sample data, code and output. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective, `grid.arrange` is redundant here. Full power of `facet_grid` to the rescue.

```
library(reshape2)
ggplot(data=melt(df, c("Days", "Brand")), aes(x=Days, y=value)) +
   geom_line(size=1) + 
   facet_grid(variable ~ Brand, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Tonytonov, Thanks for your answer. You are right for my sample dataset. I was wrong to provide only a subset that makes it looks easier than it is. I actually have 15 brands, which make the facet_grid dataset very long (horizontally or vertically). I am aiming for a more rectangular format and thus tried to find a solution of double charts on a more customizable grid (facet_wrap)

Comment: Then `facet_wrap` it instead and specify nrow/ncol?